# Increase and Decrease functions also change the size of what was previously drawn. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, function, canvas

I'm designing a drawing app in Android Studio using Java. I have a '+' button and a '-' button in my activity_main.xml. Whenever I click on these buttons the size of the pen increases or decreases, but it also increases and decreases whatever I had already drawn on the canvas. This should not be happening, why is this happening?

Code snippet of increase/decrease functions:

```
public void increasePenSize() {
        float currentStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        float newStrokeWidth = currentStrokeWidth + 2f;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(newStrokeWidth);
    }

    public void decreasePenSize() {
        float currentStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        float newStrokeWidth = currentStrokeWidth - 2f;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(newStrokeWidth);
    }
```

Full code:

```
package com.example.sketch_1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CanvasView extends View
{
    Context context;
    private int width, height;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;


    // Add variables to keep track of previous paths and their colors
    private List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentColor = Color.BLACK;
    public CanvasView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    public void changePenColor(String color) {
        switch (color) {
            case "Black":
                currentColor = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            case "Brown":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(79, 30, 14);
                break;
            case "Blue":
                currentColor = Color.BLUE;
                break;
            case "Cyan":
                currentColor = Color.CYAN;
                break;
            case "Red":
                currentColor = Color.RED;
                break;
            case "Orange":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(255, 165, 0);
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                currentColor = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            case "Dark Green":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(0, 100, 0);
                break;
            case "Light Green":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(57, 252, 3);
                break;
            case "Pink":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(250, 10, 174);
                break;
            case "Magenta":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(212, 0, 255);
                break;
            case "Purple":
                currentColor = Color.rgb(128, 0, 128);
                break;
            case "Eraser":
                currentColor = Color.WHITE;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    public void startTouch(float x, float y)
    {
//        path.reset();
        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        // Add new path to list of paths and their colors
        paths.add(path);
        colors.add(currentColor);
    }

    public void moveTouch(float x, float y)
    {
        float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

        if(dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
        {
            path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x+mX)/2, (y+mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }
    }




    // Function to clear the canvas

    public void clearCanvas()
    {
        paths.clear();
        colors.clear(); // Clears all the colors from the array
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        invalidate();
    }


    // Functions for increasing and decreasing pen size
    public void increasePenSize() {
        float currentStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        float newStrokeWidth = currentStrokeWidth + 2f;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(newStrokeWidth);
    }

    public void decreasePenSize() {
        float currentStrokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        float newStrokeWidth = currentStrokeWidth - 2f;
        paint.setStrokeWidth(newStrokeWidth);
    }


    // Text box function
//    public void showTextBox() {
//        // Create a new EditText object
//        EditText textBox = new EditText(getContext());
//
//        // Set its layout parameters
//        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
//        );
//        textBox.setLayoutParams(params);
//
//        // Add the text box to the layout
//        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.btn_text_layout); // Replace with the ID of your layout
//        layout.addView(textBox);
//    }

    // Handles all color changes from this single method function
    // Not being used right now
//    public void setPenColor(int color) {
//        paint.setColor(color);
//    }


    public void upTouch()
    {
        path.lineTo(mX, mY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Draw all paths with their respective colors
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            paint.setColor(colors.get(i));
            canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Get the x and y coordinates of the touch event
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        // Check the action of the touch event
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            // If the touch event is a down action
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Call the startTouch method and pass in the x and y coordinates
                startTouch(x, y);
                // Invalidate the view to trigger a redraw
                invalidate();
                break;
            // If the touch event is a move action
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Call the moveTouch method and pass in the x and y coordinates
                moveTouch(x, y);
                // Invalidate the view to trigger a redraw
                invalidate();
                break;
            // If the touch event is an up action
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Call the upTouch method
                upTouch();
                // Invalidate the view to trigger a redraw
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        // Return true to indicate that the event was handled
        return true;
    }


}
```

I'm expecting the increase and decrease functions to only affect what will be drawn, not what has already been drawn on the canvas. I'm not sure why it is affecting everything on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

That becomes much more complicated.  YOu're currently adding all your data to a Path.  That path gets drawn once, with whatever pen is currently set.  The simplest way to do this would be not to use a data structure like this:

```
class DrawingData {
   public Path path;
   public int strokeWidth;
}
```

Instead of storing a single Path, store a List.  Whenever the size changes, add a new DrawingData to the list.  Then in onDraw, walk the list and draw all of them, setting the strokeWidth each time.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing every `Path` in a list, and then in `onDraw` you draw each of them to the `Canvas` **using the same `Paint`**. There's no concept of *already drawn*, every call to `onDraw` starts with a blank canvas, and I assume that's why you're storing the paths and redrawing them in order?

Since you basically have to recreate the image step-by-step this way, that needs to include steps like *set size*, *set colour* etc. You could make it part of each drawing operation if you want, like in Gabe's answer (`strokeWidth` is always a parameter, even if it hasn't changed), or you could make them separate commands, like this:

```
sealed class DrawCommand {
    abstract fun perform(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint)

    data class Draw(val path: Path) : DrawCommand() {
        override fun perform(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }
    }

    data class SetStrokeWidth(val width: Float) : DrawCommand() {
        override fun perform(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
            paint.strokeWidth = width
        }
    } 
}
```

Then instead of a `List<Path>`, you hold a `List<DrawCommand>`. To add a path to it, you add a `DrawCommand.Draw(path)` instead. To set the brush width, add a `SetStrokeWidth`. To redraw the image, just iterate over all the commands, calling the common `perform` method passing the current `Canvas` and `Paint`, and they'll do what they need to do.

---

This is more complicated than just making the stroke width an attribute of each path-drawing operation, but it gives you a bit of flexibility by separating things. You can get undo functionality by popping `DrawCommand`s off the list, and you can expand it by adding new subclasses for different kinds of commands - colour changes, stroke styles, drawing circles etc etc. Depends what you need!

But either way, you need to store that stroke width change somehow, and apply it at the right stage in your redrawing.

---

The other alternative is to create your own internal `Bitmap` (and `Canvas` to wrap it), and instead of storing all your paths, just draw them to the internal bitmap. Then in `onDraw` you just use the `drawBitmap` call to render that whole bitmap in one go, instead of redrawing everything one step at a time.

On the plus side, that's a lot faster when you have a lot of paths, and it will store things like "this path is this width" because that's just how you drew it onto the bitmap, those pixels won't change if you update the `Paint` later. On the other hand, once something's drawn it's drawn (destructive editing) and you won't be able to selectively change a certain path later. You could mix the two approaches to get some flexibility, but that's getting a lot more complex!